# Data annotation [Remote] doesn't exist in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to check for a unique username in my application. I searched online and found a nice solution that uses [Remote] data annotation. However it seems like it doesn't exist in MVC 5 anymore?
Here is my references in the model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
```

If [Remote] isn't supported anymore in MVC 5, can you please suggest an optimal way to validate for uniqueness in database while creating a new entry?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[Remote]` attribute is in the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly.  You need to include that in your using statements in order to use the `[Remote]` attribute.

Here is the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) page referencing the `[Remote]` attribute as well for your reading.